# Why my switch(true) / match(true) isn't working?

Tags: php, php-8

I'm trying to implement a `switch(true)` or `match(true)` ([match is new in PHP 8](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.match.php)) to solve my problem, but it doesn't seems to work as intended:

```
return match(true) {
    //equals to false
    !!$this->jsonRequiredChecker->getMissingRequiredKey($data)  => `Parameter {$this->jsonRequiredChecker->getMissingRequiredKey($data)} is obligated`,

    //equals to true 
    !!$this->jsonFormatChecker->getIncorrectFormatKey($data)  => `Parameter {$this->jsonFormatChecker->getIncorrectFormatKey($data)} is incorrect`,
};
```

It just returns me null instead of the sentence.

```
($this->jsonFormatChecker->getIncorrectFormatKey($data)
```

returns a string by the way.

How can I return the right sentence which would be *"Parameter XXX is incorrect"*?

Comment: Is that supposed to be running a shell command? https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php

Comment: I think you want double-quotes `"` not backticks `` ` ``

Comment: I'm guessing you've been doing a lot of JS recently, and then switched to PHP. That would explain the wrong quotes, and also the awkward `!!` which in PHP can be written `(bool)`

Comment: Thanks a lot guys that was it, just some wrong quotes :)
Haha you guessed correctly @IMSoP